# C# + String Formatting

Tags: c#

I feel like I'm trying to do something simple but I am not getting the result I want. I want to display a basic number, that will always be positive. I do not want any leading zeros but I want thousands separators. For instance, for the following inputs, I want the following outputs:

```
3 -> 3
30 -> 30
300 -> 300
3000 -> 3,000
30000 -> 30,000
300000 -> 300,000
```

Currently, in an attempt to do this, I'm using the following formatting code:

```
  string text = "*Based on " + String.Format("{0:0,0}", total) + " entries";
```

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
3 -> 03
3000 -> 3,000
```

You can see how a leading "0" is added when the thousands separator is not necessary. How do I properly format my numbers?

Thank you

Comment: No it doesn't! What makes you think that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N0}", total)
```

See: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

- or -

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:#,#}", total)
```

See: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: The first will add a single decimal place, the second will not.

Comment: Notice the `0` in `N0` -- this specifies the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Use "#,##0".

See: [Quick Reference for .NET Format Strings](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other great advice, You shouldn't be using the string concatenation operator.  Simply do this:

```
string text = string.Format("*Based on {0:#,##0} entries", total);
```

This makes it easier to read, and requires less work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this format.

`{0:#,##0}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
string text = "*Based on " + total.ToString("#,##0") + " entries";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using PowerShell. The important point is that the format string is `"{0:n0}"`.

```
3, 30, 300, 3000, 30000, 300000, 3000000, 30000000 |
    %{ "{0} -> {0:n0}" -f $_ }
```

Which produces:

PS C:\Users\Damian> 3, 30, 300, 3000, 30000, 300000, 3000000, 30000000 |
    %{ "{0} -> {0:n0}" -f $_ }

```
3 -> 3
30 -> 30
300 -> 300
3000 -> 3,000
30000 -> 30,000
300000 -> 300,000
3000000 -> 3,000,000
30000000 -> 30,000,000
```